# Windows 10 and OpenSSH to encrypt a local TCP port

Tags: ssh, tcp, tunnel

I'm working on a Windows 10 machine. I wrote 2 apps: server and client.
Both of them communicate via standard TCP sockets, no encryption.
I installed OpenSSH, no certificates at the moment, just password login to keep things simple.
I don't want to expose the server listening port to the rest of the world, so it's listening on 127.0.0.1:9000. I'd like to configure the SSH server to encrypt the traffic for the port 9000, tunneling it to 9001, so that the clients could connect to the server via an encrypted socket.
I'm trying this:

```
ssh -p 22 -N -L 9001:localhost:9000 localhost
```

I would expect the client to be able to connect on localhost:9001 and, well it doesn't work.
If I understood it correctly, the tunnel should encrypt the traffic between server and client in a transparent way, like nor the server nor the client are using an encrypted socket but they should be able to communicate via the tunnel.

The output from sshd is

```
debug1: Local connections to LOCALHOST:9001 forwarded to remote address localhost:9000
debug1: Local forwarding listening on ::1 port 9001.
debug1: channel 0: new [port listener]
debug1: Local forwarding listening on 127.0.0.1 port 9001.
debug1: channel 1: new [port listener]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: Connection to port 9001 forwarding to localhost port 9000 requested.
debug1: channel 2: new [direct-tcpip]
debug1: channel 2: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 9001 for localhost port 9000, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 2408 to 127.0.0.1 port 9001, nchannels 3
debug1: Connection to port 9001 forwarding to localhost port 9000 requested.
debug1: channel 2: new [direct-tcpip]
debug1: channel 2: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 9001 for localhost port 9000, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 2411 to 127.0.0.1 port 9001, nchannels 3
debug1: Connection to port 9001 forwarding to localhost port 9000 requested.
debug1: channel 2: new [direct-tcpip]
debug1: channel 2: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 9001 for localhost port 9000, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 2413 to 127.0.0.1 port 9001, nchannels 3
```

As said, no reply from the server. Of course if I tell my client to connect straight into the port 9000 everything works fine.

I tried this approach before, for example to access a MySQL server on a remote machine. In that case it worked perfectly.

The sshd_config file is pretty standard, I tried changing a few parameters (ListenAddress, AllowTCPForwarding) with no luck.
I don't think it matters but both apps are written in Qt/C++

Thank you for all the help you might be able to provide.

Comment: ssh doesn't forward a port without a session.  It's trying to log into your system but there's no local sshd to set up a session with...

Comment: If there wasn't a session, how would I be able to login into the same machine? If I simply omit the -N switch I can login via a normal cmd session